# Is it possible to access a javascript variable when calling a js function from HTML?

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am trying to convert a Java program into HTML and JS, and in the Java code I call a method using an int from that class. Is this possible with HTML and JS? Can I write `onload="myFunc(i + 1)"` or something to that effect?

If you need it, the Java code looks like this:

```
public int i = 0;

public String chooseACard(int j) {
    if(j > cards.length - 1) j = 0;
    return cards[j].front;
}
```

and it is called by:

```
ActionListener changeFrontListener = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == nextCard) {
                textBox.setText(vc.chooseACard(vc.i + 1));
                if(vc.i + 1 > vc.cards.length - 1) vc.i = 0;
                else vc.i++;
            }
        }

    };
```

Can I do anything like this in HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: When should function be called?

Comment: It doesn't matter, someone else has solved it, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it like shown below. Basically, You can assign the handler of the event a function name or a function expression.

```js
var i = 9;

function myFunc(t){
console.log(t);}
```

```html
<button id="button1" onclick="myFunc(i + 1);">TestMe</button>
```